# Nonrecursively generating all possible permutations of elements from two arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to generate all possible equations given an String array of operators (+,-,*,/) and an String array of variables (a,b,c ...). Each equation will be composed of pairs of variables and numbers (a+ b- c/ b), except the last variable, which has no operator following it. The algorithm must generate equations of variable lengths (2 terms, 6 terms, etc). What would be the most efficient way to generate this list in Java?

Please, don't do it recursively. :)

Um, no this is not homework. Its a personal project where I'm trying to utilize genetic algorithms to find optimal equations to fit data. A description of an algorithm in general terms would suffice if you believe so.

Comment: there used to be a plz-email-me-teh-codez tag but I couldn't find it. Are you really interested in the most efficient way or just `any` way to get this off your hands? ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the no-recursion requirement? Recursion seems the natural way to go...

Comment: we could use recursion. it is the natural way to go. but when the arrays are large, the amount of recursion you need to do might exceed the stack. also, recursion introduces additional overhead and affects performance.

Comment: You need to write self-modifying assembly for this, and I only have the PPC version. Unless your on PPC?

Comment: why do we need to write self-modifying assembly?

Comment: was that a joke? oh lol.

Comment: lol @ Aiden :) Yeah, I have an APL version of that same code compiled for the original Atari console. But sometimes it deletes everything on your hard drive, so use with caution. :-P

Comment: Seriously... Penchant, you're right to worry about blowing out the stack, but OTOH any non-recursive solution to this problem will probably involve manually emulating a stack. (Which may still be more memory-efficient as you can avoid storing per-call stack frame overhead.)

Comment: How do you exclude "a+b-b+b-b+b-b...", or don't you?  If not then you would seem to have an infinite list of possibilities.

Comment: @Paul: The number of terms is specified as part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say its not homework, and I'm a trusting fellow...

1. Build a new array of variable-operator combinations by running each variable against the operator array => ["a+", "a-", "a*", "a/", "b+" ... "d/"].  We'll call this BuiltArray1
2. Run this array against the operators, outputing each and also storing each in a new array => ["a+a", "a+b", "a+c", "a+d", "a-a" ..."d/d"].  We'll call this BuiltArray2.  We can delete the original variable array ["a, "b", "c", "d"] now if we care to - we won't use it again.
3. Now things get more fun... now we are building BuiltArray3.  Run each item in BuiltArray1 against each item in BuiltArray2, outputting each and storing each in BuiltArray3 => ["a+a+a", "a-a+a", "a*a+a", "a/a+a", "b+a+a" ... "d/d/d"].  We can now delete BuiltArray2 to save some memory (this will start to consume memory quickly!)
4. For BuiltArray4 until our computer dies screaming on the last BuiltArray_n it can handle, we run each item in BuiltArray1 against the previously built array, outputting and also storing each result in a new array, then deleting the previous array.

This will chew through memory and processing power, but I can't think of anything more graceful off of the top of my head.

Hope it helps.

---

Here's Ruby codez:

```
@arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
arr2 = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
@base = []
@arr1.each do |char|
  arr2.each do |op|
    @base << char + op
  end
end
@right_vals = @arr1
loop do
  @new_values = []
  @base.each do |left|
    @right_vals.each do |right|
      val = left + right
      puts val
      @new_values << val
    end
  end
  @right_vals = @new_values
end
```

Comment: I just finished implementing something very similar to what you propose. But, instead, I just stored everything in one LinkedList instead of multiple arrays. I used previously generated solutions and tacked on an operator and a variable to get new solutions, which I added on to the list.

It does take an awful lot of memory and time, but it works.

I appreciate you not being a wierdo and trusting that this is not homework. I'll post the code in a bit.

Comment: The benefit to this solution is that you could implement this in one infinite or bounded loop that swaps out the old two arrays for the new two and then does the combining - it makes the coding short.  Always good to delete unused memory too, especially with an unbounded problem like this, where you need every bit to go further.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the code I've come up with. I'm using a single LinkedList to store the equations that I've generated. I generate all possible pairs of operators and variables, and then append them to the solutions that I've already generated to come up with new solutions. Is there a better/faster way of doing this?

```
LinkedList<String> solutions = new LinkedList<String>();
//String[] vars and operators are initialized elsewhere.
int start = 0, end = solutions.size()-1;

//creating the first solutions
for(String s : vars)
    solutions.add(s);


//precompute pairs of operators and variables
String[] pairs = new String[operators.length * vars.length];
for(int i=0, j=0; j<operators.length; j++)
for(int k=0; k<vars.length; k++)
{
    pairs[i++]= operators[j]+vars[k];
}

//while the the terms in equations is under maximum
while(solutions.get(solutions.size()-1).split("[+/*-]").length<4)
{
    for(int i=start; i<end; i++)
    {
        String soln = solutions.get(i);
        for(int j=0; j<pairs.length; j++)
        {
            solutions.add(soln+pairs[j]);
        } 
    }
    start = end +1;
    end = solutions.size()-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i also think this might be homework, I'm not giving you the code in any language but...

You can have two nested loops, one to loop through array one and the other to loop through array two.

You will see that every index combined will pass through the inner loop, and you can do your math there.

Comment: Detention! I lurk on these new-fangled cyber things, all day, just waiting for cheats!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in Java, and its recursive, but as a matter of interest the Haskell solution looks like this:

```
permuteEquations :: Int -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]
permuteEquations 1 vars _ = vars
permuteEquations n vars ops = 
    [v ++ t1 | t1 <- [o ++ t2 | t2 <- permuteEquations (n-1) vars ops, o <- ops],
               v  <- vars]
```

This generates all possible equations containing *n* variables.

Alternatively if you want a version that starts with equations of one variable (i.e. the list of variables) and then works its way up to *n* variables then it is:

```
permuteEquations1 :: Int -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]
permuteEquations1 0 _ _ = []
permuteEquations1 n vars ops = 
    [v ++ t1 | t1 <- "" : [o ++ t2 | t2 <- permuteEquations1 (n-1) vars ops, 
                                     o  <- ops], 
               v  <- vars]
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation these functions run in constant space, which is handy if you are generating billions of equations.  Does anyone know how would you do that in Java? (I'm sure its possible, I'm just curious to see what it looks like).

Actually, thanks to lazy evaluation you can get rid of the *n* term and generate an infinite list which the client truncates to whatever length it needs.

```
permuteEquations2 :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
permuteEquations2 vars ops = 
    [v ++ t1 | t1 <- "" : [o ++ t2 | t2 <- permuteEquations2 vars ops, o <- ops], 
               v  <- vars]
```

Answer (score 0):

The run time grown exponentially with the number of variables. Here is another approach.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Equations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] operators = "+ - * / %".split(" ");
        String[] variables = "a b c d e f g".split(" ");
        printAllPermutations(operators, variables);
    }

    private static void printAllPermutations(String[] operators, String[] variables) {
        if (variables.length >= 31)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need to use BigInteger to support such a large number variables.length="+variables.length);

        int permuations = 1 << variables.length;
        for(int p=1;p<permuations;p++) {
            List<String> variableList = new ArrayList<String>();
            int p2 = p;
            for (String variable : variables) {
                if ((p2 & 1) != 0)
                    variableList.add(variable);
                p2 /= 2;
            }
            printPermutations(operators, variableList.toArray(new String[variableList.size()]));
        }
    }

    private static void printPermutations(String[] operators, String[] variables) {
        long permutations = 1;
        // more accurate than Math.pow.
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length-1; i++) {
            String variable = variables[i];
            permutations *= operators.length;
        }
        for(long p = 0; p < permutations;p++) {
            long p2  = p;
            for (int i = 0; i < variables.length-1; i++) {
                System.out.print(variables[i]);
                int oper = (int) (p2 % operators.length);
                System.out.print(operators[oper]);
                p2 /= operators.length;
            }
            System.out.println(variables[variables.length-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript
>   given to sets, the first for operands, shall be applied on the second set of number, then we evaluate generated expression with a target value.

```
var targetValue=10;
var set=[2,4,8,16,64];
//var ops=['+','-', '/', '*'];

var retArray=new Array();

function permutateSigns(operand, numbers, pos, epx){

        var sum = 0;
        if (pos == numbers.length-1) {
            epx += numbers[pos];
            //console.log(epx);
            retArray.push(epx);
        } else {
            epx += (numbers[pos]) + operand;
            permutateSigns('+', numbers, pos + 1, epx);
            permutateSigns('-', numbers, pos + 1, epx);
            permutateSigns('*', numbers, pos + 1, epx);
            permutateSigns('/', numbers, pos + 1, epx);
        }
    }
permutateSigns('+',set,0,"");
var per=retArray;
console.log(per);

var validExpr;
for (var i = 0; i < retArray.length; i++) {
    var result=eval(retArray[i]);

    if(result===targetValue)
        validExpr= retArray[i];
    else
     console.log(retArray[i] + ":" + eval(retArray[i]));
}
console.log("valid expression is:" + validExpr + "; value:"+ eval(validExpr) + "number of permutations is:"+ retArray.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is pretty language-agnostic. Is this homework? It sounds like homework, so I won't give you an example, but I would use 3 `while` loops (although you could just as easily use `for` loops, I simply prefer using `while`s).

Comment: smells terribly like homework. couldn't resist adding homework tag to this question :)